# How to start a ClickOnce app from another app?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I've tried getting the launch link from the start menu and using Process.Start()
But that opens a temporary Internet Explorer window before it's actually launched. Can I avoid the temporary IE window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is... you need to create a special shortcut type of file with the extension .appref-ms that points to the app's source, and execute that file.
But there doesnt seem to be an API to create those files (and doing a text file and renaming it didnt work when I tried).
So, I ended up doing what [everybody does](http://emxmobile.com.au/_blog001/?tag=appref-ms).